# Open set in an open set

Tags: general-topology

If I have open sets $U$ and $V$ in a space $X$ $$U \subset V \subset X,$$ does it imply that the closure of $U$ is still included in $V$?

If yes, I would like to know why and if not, what would be sufficient conditions for this to hold.

Comment: What do you know about the closure of a set?

Comment: that it's the smallest closed set in which the original set is included

Comment: What if $U=V$? ${}{}$

Comment: with the subset sign i meant that it's strictly included, so they are not equal

Comment: Sorry, i have misread your question, i thought you asked if closure of U is contained in the closure of V, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

$(0,1)\subset (0,2)$ but $[0,1]$ the closure of $(0,1)$ is not contained in $(0,2)$.

Comment: ok, do you maybe know something about the sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to see why it is false is to take $U=V$